# Insert two values into the url

Tags: .net, asp.net

I would like to insert the value from `Request.QueryString["u"]` as a second parameter in the url below. So that the url read *Item.aspx?id=1&u=2*. But I can't get two server side tags to work within the NavigateUrl value field.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" 
               NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("itemID", "Item.aspx?id={0}") %>' />
```

I got errors doing it like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" 
               NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("itemID", "Item.aspx?id={0}") %>
               <%= "&u="+Request.QueryString["u"].ToString() %>' 
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out following, not sure about syntax because can't check it now:

```
NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format(
                    "Item.aspx?id={0}{1}", 
                    Eval("itemID"), 
                    Request.QueryString["u"] == null
                    ? String.Empty
                    : String.Concat("&u=", Request.QueryString["u"].ToString())); %>'
```

Comment: I forgot. Sometimes `Request.QueryString["u"]` might be null and I also don't want the *&u=* in the url when it is null. I tried to move it into a variable outside the `<%# &%>`-tags, but then the variable won't be found inside the tag.

Comment: @Niklas : see updated snippet, also you've to update original question by this new detail

Comment: @Niklas : cool! BTW, to improve readability you can extract this logic to a server side method and just call it in ASPX

Answer (score 0):

You get errors in your second example because you cannot concatenate multiple `<%# %>` expressions within a single property.

I.e, the syntax is *always*: `<tag property='<%# expression %>' />`

An example for such an expression can be found in sll's answer. Since you added a question to his answer, I'll shamelessly steal his answer and add the feature you require:

> I forgot. Sometimes Request.QueryString["u"] might be null and I also don't want the &u= in the url when it is null. I tried to move it into a variable outside the <%# &%>-tags, but then the variable won't be found inside the tag.

In that case, use a conditional (with the ternary `?:` operator):

```
NavigateUrl='<%# "Item.aspx?id=" + Eval("itemID") +
                 (Request.QueryString["u"] != null
                  ? "&u=" + Request.QueryString["u"] : "") %>'
```

You don't need `ToString`, since `QueryString["u"]` already returns a string. What you should do, however, is to correctly encode the text, since the string might contain `&` or other special characters that "break" your URL:

```
NavigateUrl='<%# "Item.aspx?id=" + Eval("itemID") +
                 (Request.QueryString["u"] != null
                  ? "&u=" + Server.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["u"]) 
                  : "") %>'
```